# Maven Archetype generate proxy issue, searching for remote catalog

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

Maven seem to be having a bug related to proxy when fetching archetype from maven's remote catalog.

My computer is behind a proxy server. I am trying to generate a project from maven command line.

```
 D:\test>mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=scala-archetype-simple -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.sparktest -DartifactId=myspark -DarchetypeGroupId=net.alchim31.maven -DarchetypeVersion=1.6 -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -e -X

[DEBUG] Searching for remote catalog: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

[DEBUG] Archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:scala-archetype-simple:1.6 doesn't exist
org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DownloadNotFoundException: 
Requested org.apache.maven.archetypes:scala-archetype-simple:jar:1.6 download does not exist.
```

Below Eclipse Bugs are related, however the issue seems to be with maven rather than Eclipse. 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390183#add_comment

Please note there is no issue working on existing maven project. The dependencies get downloaded without any issue once maven proxy is configured in settings.xml. The issue comes when generating a project using archetype:generate and using maven remote archetype-catalog.
Maven archetype-catelog can be opened in a browser without any issue
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Comment: Hello, it seems that the bug is clearly identified in Eclipse. You should precise what you're expecting. If you're looking for a workaround, I suggest you to not use Eclipse and to use Maven with command line instead.

Comment: The example i posted is using maven command line. The eclipse example is just to corroborate the fact that issue does existing in maven and eclipse with reciprocate this by returning empty catalog.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that `scala-archetype-simple` archetype with groupId `org.apache.maven.archetypes` doesn't actually exist.

You should try one of these :

- [net.alchim31.maven](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.alchim31.maven%7Cscala-archetype-simple%7C1.6%7Cmaven-archetype)
- [org.scala-tools.archetypes](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.scala-tools.archetypes%7Cscala-archetype-simple%7C1.3%7Cmaven-archetype)

Comment: I was able to create project using archetype from proxy environment, so i can confirm this is NOT a maven issue. I have however corrected the mvn command in my post. So its probably the eclipse issue. Please downvote this question if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue and the following  worked for me: have two proxies, one for http and one for https.

```
<proxy>
   <id>my-proxy-http</id>
   <active>true</active>
   <protocol>http</protocol>
   <host>xx.xx.x.xxx</host>
   <port>8080</port>
   <username>myusername</username>
   <password>mypassword</password>
</proxy>
<proxy>
   <id>my-proxy-https</id>
   <active>true</active>
   <protocol>https</protocol>
   <host>xx.xx.x.xxx</host>
   <port>8080</port>
   <username>myusername</username>
   <password>mypassword</password>
</proxy>
```